# efficient paging in dataset when two tabs are simultaneously opened in browser of same site

Tags: c#

I have a website of B2B Portal,
when I am search the Products in SearchProduct textbox provided by website,and click search then new tab1 opened with results in datalist OK
Then
I search another Product from Main tab of site then result Tab is opened in new tab2,
Now Problem is there,
when I am Do page next in Paging of datalist in tab1, I found the next page is filled from Last seach Products(I mean what we search second as already  tab1 is opened) 
!
Got it

Please explain me how  to paging in datalist with dataset that is assigned it.

Comment: Which server technology? ASP.NET WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my code error for this issue. actually some one has stored searched result in CACHE variable and it is application level so if other user will search then if last user turn to next page then it will show latest searched result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tabs share the session id, hence the session data, including the paging info. One solution consists in passing the page number either through a post or in the query part of the URL.